# Cookie share with subdomain nodejs httponly cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, express-session

I am using express-session module for maintain session. i have two app. i want to share cookies with this apps, parent app run in example.com , and child app run in child.example.com. i set httponly cookie using express-session it sets in the child app.i can verified that cookie in resource tab in chrome debugger.

Network tab:

When the first call to sub-domain:
   it load like "http://www.child.example.com" cookie set in the request. while the url is redirect to server IP . cookie not available after that.

like http://13.25.230.2/index cookie not avaliable on that

Answer (score 5):

When you send the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header, you can [specify the domain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) it is for.

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

The domain must be a suffix of the domain hosting the page.

i.e. `foo.example.com`, `bar.baz.example.com` and `www.example.com` can all share a cookie belonging to `example.com`.

A URL using an IP address has no hostname in it at all and cannot match that rule.

There is no way to share your cookie between `example.com` and `13.25.230.2`. Give the site a hostname instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can set cookie using setcookie header from one host to another. For example from example.com to foobar.com. 
If you have to do it. Then do it by passing  the cookie value to server side script for example foobar.com\set-my-cookie.php and use to to save the cookie.

Httponly cookies cannot be set or read from client side code.