# Is there a way to include your cookies into a websocket request to another domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, websocket

I have a web app running on x.example.com and it sets a cookie. In the client side of this app, is there a way to include the cookie (from x.example.com) into a web socket connection request to another server on y.example.com?

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://y.example.com/ws");
```

The cookie is http only.

Comment: Possible answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268764/cookie-share-with-subdomain-nodejs-httponly-cookie

Comment: @GanapatiVS Thanks, this may be an option. But I still wonder if there is a possibility to include cookies like in cross-domain AJAX request somehow.

Comment: You cannot read httpOnly cookie in browser. so, you cannot send them manually.